# Unknown directive "lua_package_path" when trying to start nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, openid-connect, resty

I am getting this when trying to start my nginx service

> unknown directive "lua_package_path"

Can someone please help me understand what it is looking for? I have both lua-resty-openidc and lua-resty-hmac installed but I just don't know what to point this to.

Comment: How have you configured your nginx service? Share your configuration file(s).

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but have a look a the last post on [this](https://github.com/sumory/orange/issues/132) thread.

Answer (score 2):

My bad .. I didnt realise when you instll OpenResty you need to then start Openresty with service openresty start.

I was doing service nginx start

Answer (score 0):

There are now modules available for Nginx to enable lua/openresty functionality so for example you can install it on Debian (e.g. Ubuntu) based system:

```
sudo apt install libnginx-mod-http-lua
```

This should then provide lua/openresty functionality - provided your system includes the correct modules in the `nginx.conf` file - as happens on Ubuntu - i.e. it contains a line like this `include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;` which should include a mod-http-lua.conf file containing:

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;
```